# Keeping trailing zeroes with plotmath

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

I'm using `annotate()` to overlay text on one of my `ggplot2` plots. I'm using the option `parse=T` because I need to use the Greek letter rho. I'd like the text to say `= -0.50`, but the trailing zero gets clipped and I get `-0.5` instead.

Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
x<-rnorm(50)
y<-rnorm(50)
df<-data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
geom_point()+
annotate(geom="text",x=1,y=1,label="rho==-0.50",parse=T)
```

Does anyone know how I can get the last 0 to show up? I thought I could use `paste()` like this:

```
annotate(geom="text",x=1,y=1,label=paste("rho==-0.5","0",sep=""),parse=T)
```

but then I get the error:

```
Error in parse(text = lab) : <text>:1:11: unexpected numeric constant
1: rho==-0.5 0
             ^
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is an `plotmath` expression parsing problem; it's not `ggplot2` related.

What you can do is ensure that `0.50` is interpreted as a character string, not a numeric value which will be rounded:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_point() +
    annotate(geom="text", x=1, y=1, label="rho=='-0.50'", parse=T)
```

You would get the same behavior using `base`:

```
plot(1, type ='n')
text(1.2, 1.2, expression(rho=='-0.50'))
text(0.8, 0.8, expression(rho==0.50))
```

If you want a more general approach, try something like

```
sprintf('rho == "%1.2f"',0.5)
```

There is an [r-help thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Format-of-numbers-in-plotmath-expressions-td4645126.html) related to this issue.